# How to rollback saved changes in WebAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using the Web API framework to provide backend services for my frontend HTML5 application. I use Entity Framework for Object Relation Mapping. The Web API exposes a set of methods over HTTP for data manipulation, and the frontend consumes the WebAPI for data manipulation (retrieve, insert, update, etc.).

Below is how I perform a database operation in a Web API repository:

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private PersonDetailsContext personContext;

    public PersonRepository(PersonDetailsContext personContext)
    {
        this.personContext= personContext;
    }

public sResponse DeleteAccImage(ACCTIMAGE medAccImg)
    {
        sResponse sRes = new sResponse();
        sRes.IsSuccess = false;

        try
        {
            MEDACCTIMAGE medAccImgDelete = personContext.ACCTIMAGE.Where(X => X.ACCOUNT == medAccImg.ACCOUNT && X.CODE == medAccImg.CODE).SingleOrDefault();

            if (medAccImgDelete == null)
            {
                sRes.outMessage = "Image does not exist for Account = " + medAccImg.ACCOUNT;
                return sRes;
            }

            personContext.ACCTIMAGE.Remove(medAccImgDelete);
            personContext.SaveChanges();

            sRes.IsSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.EntityException ex)
        {
            sRes.outMessage = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sRes.outMessage = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }

        return sRes;
    }
}
```

And this is the controller that maps the frontend request to the above repository method:

```
    [ActionName("PostDeleteAccImage")]
    [APIAuthentication]
    public sResponse PostDeleteAccImage(ACCTIMAGE accImg)
    {   
        //here i'm getting database name dynamically to connect to a database specified from front end
        IPersonRepository personRep = new personRepository(new PersonDetailsContext(PersonRepository.GetDBConnectionString(accImg.DataBaseName)));
        sResponse sResult = personRep.DeleteAccImage(medAccImg);
        return sResult;
    }
```

Here is my question:

After calling `SaveChanges()`, is it possible to rollback the changes done in one Web API call using another Web API method call?

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, because I guess that for each API request the context wont be the same (i.e a new instance of the API will be created so it won't aware of the previous context, am I right?).

Is there any way to rollback changes of previous API calls?

Comment: A couple of things, why would you like to roll back if there was a success SaveChanges? You are re throwing the exception so you will never send the answer back to the caller, don't re throw it

Comment: I think you could use transactions, please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx. You can make the transaction fail in certain cases which is going to roll back.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @dariogriffo after saving some changes there may be some post check conditions if those conditions fails i need to rollback the changes made previously.the thing is those conditions checked in front end side...and regarding throwing errors, i ill take your point. thanks. :)

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Thank you..You can see in my controller method, For each request form front end i'm creating a new repository instance to serve that request..so the context instance wont be same for all requests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: AFAIK, no.  Once you have called saveChanges() the SQL statements were issued to your database and the database transaction has committed.  The only way to roll that back would be something custom you implement, not a database transaction or EF data context thing.

Long answer: You are correct that each request into your API will have a different data context (based on your above code where you new up a context in the action method).  Also, please reconsider wrapping all of your EF operation behind a repository.  Here are some [viewpoints](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/) from [smart](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) people that [describe](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) how this can needlessly complicate your code.

One idea is to "stage" your changes/inserts to a table that you then run your checks against.  If the checks pass, move the changes into the real table(s), otherwise delete them from the staged table.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs on this. :) staging seems to be a good idea to solve this issue..